# Messaging with jetpack compose but the topbar disappears when clicking on the textfield

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, adjustpan

I am making a messaging application with Jetpack compose, when textfield enable, topbar is hidden upwards

```
 Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(modifier = Modifier
                .height(50.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)),
                title = {
                    Row {
                        Box(modifier = Modifier
                            .size(40.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)){
                            Image(modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .clip(CircleShape),bitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(R.drawable.numan) , contentDescription = null, contentScale = ContentScale.Crop  )

                        }
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 2.dp))
                        Text(modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(top = 12.dp)
                            .fillMaxHeight(),
                            text = username.toString(), fontFamily = googleSans, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
                        )
                    }
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    Icon(modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .width(30.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            navController.navigateUp()
                        },imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "back", tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary)
                }
                ,colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
                    contentColorFor(backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary),
                ))
        }
    , containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
```

When I set windowSoftInputMode:adjustResize, the messaging screen works as I want, but other screens with textfields (for example login screen) were distorted.Although I tried all the ways such as AdjustPan, it did not give the result I wanted, I did it directly in the surface before scaffold, I changed it this way, but the problem was not solved again, how to solve this problem, thank you to everyone who helps me in advance.

````
 OutlinedTextField(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                    value = myMessage.value,
                    onValueChange ={
                        myMessage.value = it
                    }, trailingIcon ={
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Send,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary)
                    },
                    placeholder = {
                        Text(text = "Mesaj Yaz...")
                    },
                    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                        focusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                        unfocusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                        cursorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                        focusedTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                        unfocusedTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                        focusedPlaceholderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                        unfocusedPlaceholderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                        selectionColors = TextSelectionColors(handleColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
                    ),
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences)
                )
            }
        }

    }```
````